# Java Concurrency using locks

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm processing a graph and it works sequentially and now I want to improve its performance by processing it concurrently.

Here's what I'm doing:

- I traverse all of the edges in the graph on each iteration.
- Each iteration produces an output array that's fed into the next
  iteration.
- To process the graph concurrently, I'm partitioning the graph based
  on the number of threads, I'm using and I'm synchronising the threads after each iteration using barriers.

**Here's my code, I left out some variable declarations, methods etc for brevity**

---

```
class Worker implements Runnable {
    ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    void run() {
        while (true) {
            barrier.await();
            lock.lock();

            iterate(input_array, output_array);

            lock.unlock();
            barrier.await();
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
class ProcessGraph {

    void iterate(input_array, output_array) {

        for (int i = 0; i < num_of_edges; i++) {
            int processed_number = process_edge(i);
            output_array[destinations[i]] += processed_number;
        }

    }

}
```

The declarations array holds vertices and is smaller than the `num_of_edges`, so there'll be some overlap when writing to output_array.

I placed a lock around my iterate method in each thread to ensure writing to output_array is atomic.

**The problem**
Since each iteration is just adding to the previous one, the code always produces the correct answer, even if it doesn't execute atomically.

I thought that adding the locks would ensure `output_array[destinations[i]] += processed_number;` is executed atomically.

So if two threads tried to write to `output_array` at the same time, one would be forced to wait.

I don't think it is because when executed with the locks and without the locks, my code runs at the same speed and I don't know how to check that the code is being executed atomically.

Comment: If each `Worker` uses its own `ReentrantLock` then they won't be able to synchronize (or mutex) with any other worker.

Comment: Please, expand your question, it is not clear what issue you have met.

Comment: you probably need `static` lock.